# mypy complaining that popen.stdout does not have a .readline

Tags: python, mypy

I'm trying to tell mypy that the following function should yield Unicode strings (i.e. `str` on py3 and `unicode` on py2):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
from typing import Iterator
import subprocess

def popen_readline():  # type: () -> Iterator[str]
    popen = subprocess.Popen(
        ['ls'],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        cwd=os.getcwd(),
        shell=True
    )
    for line in iter(popen.stdout.readline, b""):
        yield line.decode()
```

`mypy` without the `-2` flag passes without any comments, but when adding the `-2` flag I get:

```
c:\srv\tmp> mypy popenstdout.py -2
popenstdout.py:14: error: Item "None" of "Optional[IO[Any]]" has no attribute "readline"
popenstdout.py:15: error: Incompatible types in "yield" (actual type "unicode", expected type "str")
```

This is my first attempt at using mypy.. is it possible to specify the type of this function so it will work on both py2 and py3?

Changing the type to `() -> Iterator[Union[unicode,str]]` will remove the second error on py2 (but not the first); and on py3 it causes:

```
popenstdout.py:6: error: Name 'unicode' is not defined
```

Comment: Python 3 doesn't have a `unicode()` function, as strings are natively unicode already.

Comment: the pipes you get from Popen use binary data,  in Python3 that is the `bytes` type.  i do not recall how Python2 deals with it but i can believe they would not support .readline although pipes can be used for text.

Comment: i recommend learning and using Python3 exclusively.  i have been doing so since the beginning of 2018.  support for Python2 comes to an end at the end of *this* year (2019).  Python3 has all the complications of Unicode and bytes worked out.

Comment: @Skaperen I've been coding in Python since 1997, this is for a project where we're transitioning 160KLOC of Py2 to Py3.

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm not sure what you are trying to say... mypy is supposed to work for both py2 and py3 code, so I'm assuming there is a solution..?

Comment: @Skaperen both py2 and py3 support `popen.stdout.readline`. The problem is not with the functionality (they both deal with byte strings). The problem is with providing a type that the mypy type system understands...

Comment: I'm saying that Python 3 does not have a `unicode()` function, therefore it is understandable that you would get this error with Python 3.  I have no idea what `mypy` is, so I can't help with that.

Comment: @JohnGordon `mypy` is a static type checker for python, and is the raison-d'etre for the type hints that were added to py3. Thanks for commenting though...

Comment: You can use [`typing.Text`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Text) as a 2/3-compatible `unicode`/`str`-type, so simply add the import and change `Iterator[str]` to `Iterator[Text]`.

Comment: As for the other error (`Item "None" of "Optional[IO[Any]]" has no attribute "readline"`), two things. `IO[Any]` indeed does make little sense here, and it was changed to `IO[bytes]` recently ([PR #3132](https://github.com/python/typeshed/pull/3132)), so `mypy==0.730` will sort that out (or install the dev version for testing, `pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps git+https://github.com/python/mypy`).

Comment: The `Optional` is necessary because `Popen.stdout` can be `None` at runtime, and `mypy` does static code analysis. You can either turn off the strict none checking by passing the `--no-strict-optional` flag via command line or `mypy.ini`, or add an `assert popen.stdout is not None` in the code. Read more about it here: [Unexpected errors about ‘None’ and/or ‘Optional’ types](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#unexpected-errors-about-none-and-or-optional-types). Hope that helps!

Comment: @hoefling I understand what you're saying, but if mypy does enough data-flow analysis to discover that `assert popen.stdout is not None`, then it probably should be able to figure out that this particular `Popen(..)` call will always generate an object with a `stdtout` that is not None. In any case, the error message leaves a lot to be desired (which is my general feeling about mypy after a week of usage...)

Comment: _... this particular Popen(..) call will always generate an object with a stdtout that is not None_ - that's not quite true. This is only the case if `os.pipe()`/`winapi.CreatePipe()` actually return writable descriptors. I agree that `mypy`'s semantic analysis is pretty limited (although it has improved a lot lately), but it's just not possible to infer the value of `popen.stdout` without executing os specific code, due to `Popen` implementation. In the end, it's either injecting custom asserts or doing explicit casts.

Comment: @hoefling You're talking about run-time errors, though, not type-errors - i.e. the asserts for `os.pipe()` etc. returning usable streams should be in the Popen ctor, then it can return a type that is guaranteed to expose a `.stdout`. The problem could be solved without dataflow analysis if you could overload the type of a function (`Popen(...stdout:Pipe...) -> PopenWithStdout`), I'm not holding my breath though ;-)